# Sequence of functions having a convergent subsequence

Tags: real-analysis

let $V=$ space of all continuous functions on R with compact support endowed with $d(f,g)=(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(t)-g(t)|^2dt)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Define $f\in V$ .define $f_n=f(x-n)$ Then show that $f_n$ has no convergent subsequence.

I don't know how to start it.There is a similar version of this question.I am not getting it.Can anyone show an easier version of this

Comment: What's your problem with the previous version

Comment: I cant understand that.Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the following.

Let $f\in V$ be an arbitrary non-zero function. Since the function $f$ is continuous, $d(f,0)>0$. Since the support $\text{supp } f$ of the function $f$ is compact, there exists a number $M$ such that $\text{supp } f\subset[-M,M].$ Suppose that the sequence $\{f_n\}$ has a convergent subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$. Then the sequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ is fundamental, that is for each $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a number $K=K(\varepsilon)>0$ such that $d(f_{n_k}, f_{n_k’})<\varepsilon$ provided $k,k’>K$. Let $k>K(\sqrt{2}d(f,0))$ be an arbitrary number and $k’$ be such a number that $n_k’>n_k+2M$. Since $\text{supp } f_{n_k}\cap \text{supp } f_{n_k’}=\varnothing$,

$$d(f_{n_k}, f_{n’_k})=\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}| f_{n_k}(t)-f_{n’_k}(t)|^2dt\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=$$
$$\left(\int_{\text{supp } f_{n_k}}| f_{n_k}(t)-f_{n’_k}(t)|^2dt+\int_{\text{supp } f_{n’_k}}| f_{n_k}(t)-f_{n’_k}(t)|^2dt\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=$$ $$
\left(\int_{\text{supp } f_{n_k}}| f_{n_k}(t)|^2dt+\int_{\text{supp } f_{n’_k}}|f_{n’_k}(t)|^2dt\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=$$ $$
\left(2\int_{\text{supp } f}| f (t)|^2dt\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt{2}d(f,0),$$

a contradiction.

Comment: @ Alex       im not  getting  how  u directly  write  $d(f_{n_k}, f_{n_k’})=2d(f,0),$ ??

Comment: @jasmine  Thanks for your remark. I corrected and extended my answer.